# Error Status 422 for Clerk Authentication Migration Script

Tags: authentication, clerk, http-status-code-422

I've been trying to test out the Clerk's Migration script with some dummy users and a test Clerk project. However, I keep getting this error called status 422, where it says that form data is missing. I've checked and double checked my JSON file inputs, the index.ts code and cannot seem to figure out where the missing data can be. Has anyone ever dealt with this issue before or knows a way to fix it?

Here is the exact error message from the migration log:

```
{
  "userId": "89",
  "status": 422,
  "clerkTraceId": "41cfcb7bd30342c6ed60c4efe65a5a6b",
  "clerkError": true,
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "form_data_missing",
      "message": "missing data",
      "meta": {}
    }
  ],
  "originalLine": 155,
  "originalColumn": 12
}
```

Here is the code for my users.json file (just one user):

```
[
  {
    "externalId": "89",
    "email": "user89@example.com",
    "firstName": "User89",
    "lastName": "Lastname89",
    "password": "$2a$12$9HhLqMJxqBKhlZasxjlhger67GFcC4aOAtpcU.THpcSLiQve4mq6.",
    "passwordHasher": "bcrypt"
  }
]
```

Here is the index.ts code:

```
import { config } from "dotenv";
config();

import * as fs from "fs";
import * as z from "zod";
import clerkClient from "@clerk/clerk-sdk-node";
import ora, { Ora } from "ora";

const SECRET_KEY = process.env.CLERK_SECRET_KEY;
const DELAY = parseInt(process.env.DELAY_MS ?? `1_000`);
const RETRY_DELAY = parseInt(process.env.RETRY_DELAY_MS ?? `10_000`);
const IMPORT_TO_DEV = process.env.IMPORT_TO_DEV_INSTANCE ?? "false";
const OFFSET = parseInt(process.env.OFFSET ?? `0`);

if (!SECRET_KEY) {
  throw new Error(
    "CLERK_SECRET_KEY is required. Please copy .env.example to .env and add your key."
  );
}

if (SECRET_KEY.split("_")[1] !== "live" && IMPORT_TO_DEV === "false") {
  throw new Error(
    "The Clerk Secret Key provided is for a development instance. Development instances are limited to 500 users and do not share their userbase with production instances. If you want to import users to your development instance, please set 'IMPORT_TO_DEV_INSTANCE' in your .env to 'true'."
  );
}

const userSchema = z.object({
  externalId: z.string(),
  email: z.string().email(),
  firstName: z.string().optional(),
  lastName: z.string().optional(),
  password: z.string().optional(),
  passwordHasher: z
    .enum([
      "argon2i",
      "argon2id",
      "bcrypt",
      "md5",
      "pbkdf2_sha256",
      "pbkdf2_sha256_django",
      "pbkdf2_sha1",
      "scrypt_firebase",
    ])
    .optional(),
});

type User = z.infer<typeof userSchema>;

const createUser = (userData: User) =>
  userData.password
    ? clerkClient.users.createUser({
        externalId: userData.externalId,
        emailAddress: [userData.email],
        firstName: userData.firstName,
        lastName: userData.lastName,
        password: userData.password
      })
    : clerkClient.users.createUser({
        externalId: userData.externalId,
        emailAddress: [userData.email],
        firstName: userData.firstName,
        lastName: userData.lastName,
        skipPasswordRequirement: true,
      });

const now = new Date().toISOString().split(".")[0]; // YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss
function appendLog(payload: any) {
  fs.appendFileSync(
    `./migration-log-${now}.json`,
    `\n${JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2)}`
  );
}

let migrated = 0;
let alreadyExists = 0;

async function processUserToClerk(userData: User, spinner: Ora) {
  const txt = spinner.text;
  try {
    const parsedUserData = userSchema.safeParse(userData);
    if (!parsedUserData.success) {
      throw parsedUserData.error;
    }
    await createUser(parsedUserData.data);

    migrated++;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.status === 422) {
      console.log(error)
      appendLog({ userId: userData.externalId, ...error });
      alreadyExists++;
      return;
    }

    // Keep cooldown in case rate limit is reached as a fallback if the thread blocking fails
    if (error.status === 429) {
      spinner.text = `${txt} - rate limit reached, waiting for ${RETRY_DELAY} ms`;
      await rateLimitCooldown();
      spinner.text = txt;
      return processUserToClerk(userData, spinner);
    }

    appendLog({ userId: userData.externalId, ...error });
  }
}

async function cooldown() {
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, DELAY));
}

async function rateLimitCooldown() {
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, RETRY_DELAY));
}

async function main() {
  console.log(`Clerk User Migration Utility`);

  const inputFileName = process.argv[2] ?? "users.json";

  console.log(`Fetching users from ${inputFileName}`);

  const parsedUserData: any[] = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync(inputFileName, "utf-8")
  );

  const offsetUsers = parsedUserData.slice(OFFSET);
  console.log(
    `users.json found and parsed, attempting migration with an offset of ${OFFSET}`
  );

  let i = 0;
  const spinner = ora(`Migrating users`).start();

  for (const userData of offsetUsers) {
    spinner.text = `Migrating user ${i}/${offsetUsers.length}, cooldown`;
    await cooldown();
    i++;
    spinner.text = `Migrating user ${i}/${offsetUsers.length}`;
    await processUserToClerk(userData, spinner);
  }

  spinner.succeed(`Migration complete`);
  return;
}

main().then(() => {
  console.log(`${migrated} users migrated`);
  console.log(`${alreadyExists} users failed to upload`);
  console.log(alreadyExists)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we answered in the Clerk Discord https://discord.com/channels/856971667393609759/1212214526129479731

The answer ended up being

> The "code": "form_data_missing", error indicates that something required by the script or the application configuration is missing. You are passing just email, name and password. Do you have something like phone number or user name turned on and set required in your dashboard

Removing that requirement in the dashboard cleared up the Migration script to continue creating users.